# Contar números negativos de un array en php

Tags: php, array, revisión-de-código

Tengo que contar los números negativos de un array, pero no consigo dar con la tecla, mi código es el siguiente, he probado la función para contar elementos de un array pero no consigo nada, así que dejo lo que estoy probando ahora:

```
<?php
    //Creamos el array
    echo "El array con números aleatorios es:</br>";
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++) {
            $numalet = mt_rand(-99, 99);
            $arrayalet[$i] = $numalet;
        }
        print_r($arrayalet);
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    //Apartado uno
    $maximo = max($arrayalet);
    echo "El máximo es $maximo </br>";
    //Apartado dos
    $minimo = min($arrayalet);
    echo "El mínimo es $minimo </br>";
    //Apartado tres
    $media = array_sum($arrayalet) / 30;
    echo "La media es $media </br>";
    //Apartado 4
         foreach ($arrayalet as $indice => $valor) {
                    if ((substr($valor, -1) == '-')){
                    $arrayResultados[] = $valor;
                    }
                }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Hay varias posibilidades de contar negativos:

Usaremos funciones, para ser más prácticos:

**Opción 1: En un bucle [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php):**

Pasamos `$array_for` a la función `get_negativosfor`:

```
 $array_for=array(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -45, -89, 4);
 $negativos_for=get_negativosfor($array_for);
 echo "Negativos usando for: ".$negativos_for;

/* 
 *El uso de funciones es más elegante y práctico, 
 *sobre todo si necesitas llamarlas desde varias partes de tu código
 *La función evalúa cada número ($x) de $array y si éste es menor que 0
 *incrementa un contador $i en 1 cada vez. Al final devuelve el total del contador
 */

    function get_negativosfor($array) { 
         $i = 0; foreach ($array as $x) 
                    if ($x < 0) $i++; 
         return $i; 
    }
```

***Resultado:***

```
Negativos usando for: 5
```

---

**Opción 2: Con [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php):**
Es útil sobre todo si necesitas no sólo contar los valores, sino también cuáles son e incluso qué posición ocupan en el array. **Nótese que en la llamada se usa el nombre de la función, en este caso `get_negativosfiltro`**

```
$arr_filtro= array(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -4, -45, -89, 4);
$arr_negativos=array_filter($arr_filtro, 'get_negativosfiltro');
$negativos_filtro=count ($arr_negativos);

echo "Negativos usando array_filter: ". $negativos_filtro."<br>";
echo "Valores negativos y su posición en el array: <br>";
print_r($arr_negativos);

function get_negativosfiltro($array){
    return is_numeric($array) && $array < 0;
}
```

***Resultado:***

```
Negativos usando array_filter: 5
Valores negativos y su posición en el array: 
Array ( [0] => -2 [1] => -1 [6] => -4 [7] => -45 [8] => -89 )
```

---

**Opción 3: Usando [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-grep.php)**

```
$el_array = array(1, 2, -4, -1, 4, -2, 5, -10, -5, 45, 10, 67, -0.23, 7, -1016.86, -1);

$negativos = preg_grep("/^\-\d*\.?\d+$/", $el_array);

print_r($negativos);

echo 'El array cuenta con ' . count($negativos) . ' números negativos';
```

***Resultado*:**

```
Array ( [2] => -4 [3] => -1 [5] => -2 [7] => -10 [8] => -5 [12] => -0.23 [14] => -1016.86 [15] => -1 ) 

El array cuenta con 8 números negativos
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrias intentar que en vez de buscar en el arreglo cuales son negativos, podrias recorrer el arreglo sacar el elemento y condicionar a que si es menor que cero que incremente un contador y al final retornas el contador y tendras cuantos numero negativos tiene tu arreglo.

Comment: Gracias, es que estoy pegadísimo en un montón de conceptos

Answer (score 3):

También podrías resolverlo usando:

- [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php): para iterar un array y reducirlo a un solo valor usando una función.

Ejemplo:

```
$total = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $number) {
  return $carry + ($number < 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando verificas si el valor es negativo es mejor utilizar `< 0` en vez de ver si tiene el signo negativo y además con un contador. Por ejemplo así:

```
$cont = 0

foreach ($arrayalet as $valor) {
   if ($valor < 0))
       $cont ++;
}

echo "La cantidad de números negativos es de: ". $cont;
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `preg_grep` en un array para devolver las entradas que coincidan con la expresión regular:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -2, 5, -100, -5, 245, 10, 67, -0.23, 76, -100.23);

$negativos = preg_grep("/^\-\d*\.?\d+$/", $numeros);

print_r($negativos);
```

Teniendo el `array` con los números negativos solo te faltaría usarlo o contar la cantidad de valores contenidos en él usando `count`.

Aquí te dejo [un ejemplo en Ideone](http://ideone.com/AfTpJL).

Answer (score 1):

esta opción tambien es valida

```
//$arrayalet = [0,1,5,-7,-8]; // dejo esto como ejemplo
echo count(array_filter($arrayalet, function($value, $key) {
    return $value < 0;
}));
```

Te sirve para filtrar otras cosas tambien, de esta forma PHP lo tiene mas optimizado que un simple **for**

Comment: ¿$v, y $k qué son?

Comment: $v = valor (value) $k = llave (key); voy a editar la respuesta para que se entienda mejor esta forma es muy comun en PHP en algunos foros incluso en el manual de PHP OFICIAL, menos mal que preguntastes te queda como conocimiento personal