# Bucle foreach no me funciona correctamente en <select>

Tags: php, html

Buenas,

Tengo un editor de artículos donde uno de los campos que tiene que "recoger" es el juego al que pertenece. Lo he hecho con un bucle debido a que son unos 2.000 juegos y no voy a crear un  por cada juego manualmente, además que va cambiando. El código que tengo es este:

```
<select class="select" name="juego">
   <option value="Ninguno" <?php if ($juego == 'Ninguno') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Ninguno</option>
   <?php foreach ($games as $game): ?>
   <?php

   $game_title = $game['titulo'];
   $titular = trim($game['titulo']);

   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $game_title ?>" <?php if ($juego == "<?php echo $titular ?>") {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $game['titulo'] ?></option>

   <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

Como veis el primer  lo meto manualmente porque hay artículos que no están vinculados a ningún juego y para ello uso el valor de "ninguno".

`$games` es un array que contiene todos los juegos y de donde obtengo los nombres de los juegos. Lo que me estoy dando cuenta es que al bucle no entra más que en una ocasión, la primera, porque el valor de $game_title es siempre el mismo, que coincide con el nombre del primero juego del array `$games`.

Comment: en la pregunta hablas de `$game` y en el codigo aparece `$games` (plural). Irá por ahí el problema? hiciste un `var_dump` de `$games` para corroborar que es un array y no algún otro tipo de dato?

Comment: Perdón, `$games` es el array completo y `$game` hace mención al array específico de cada juego. He probado ya con `var_dump` y están todos los datos bien, pero no se muestran.

Comment: No me dejaba ya mencionarte @PabloAlcantar

Comment: No veo de buenas a primeras el error. Me llama la atención la línea `<?php if ($juego == "<?php echo $titular ?>") {echo 'selected';} ?>` ahi tienes un error conceptual, ya que no comparas con `$titular`, si no que con "<?php echo 1 ?>" (si `$titular = 1`, ya que se expande la cadena). Podrías poner un trozo de `var_export($games);` ?

Comment: @PabloAlcantar Puede que el error esté en esa comprobación. Suelo usar esa línea de código para que me cargue los datos del valor de <select>, aunque tampoco veo el error que comentas. `$juego` es una variable que en el momento de pinchar sobre editar el artículo coge un valor, y `$titular` es una variable que cada vez que entra en el bucle foreach tiene un valor distinto, se supone que recorre todos los títulos de los juegos, hasta que uno de ellos coincide, y es el que se debería de mostrar en el <select>.

Comment: @PabloAlcantar He probado también a hacer un `var_export($games)` pero se ha crasheado el navegador.

Comment: buen dia por favor verifica esto, creo que se adapta a lo que necesitas http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51039/contar-n%C3%BAmeros-negativos-de-un-array-en-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el fallo lo tienes en el código, prueba con este código a ver

```
<select class="select" name="juego">
   <option value="Ninguno" <?php if ($juego == 'Ninguno') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Ninguno</option>
   <?php foreach ($games as $game){ ?>
   <?php

   $game_title = $game['titulo'];
   $titular = trim($game['titulo']);

   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $game_title ?>" <?php if ($juego == $titular) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $game['titulo'] ?></option>

   <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: la linea `<?php if ($juego == "<?php echo $titular ?>")` parece que esta mal, en todo caso seria : `<?php if ($juego ==  $titular )`

Comment: @nachfren, tienes razón, solo me había fijado en el foreach, ya lo he modificado

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡solucionado con la respuesta que me has dado! Imagino que sería más por haber puesto dentro de las etiquetas PHP otras etiquetas de apertura y cierre. ¡Muchas gracias!